# how to mimic ggplot2's plus operator?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am writing a package to build D3plus plots following `ggplot2` style

To the moment things like this work well:

```
d3plus() %>% 
  d3p_type("treemap") %>% 
  d3p_data(dta) %>% 
  d3p_groupby(c("parent","id"))
```

This is purely sugar syntax but I really want to mimic `ggplot2` plus operator so I tried to append an S3 class to my functions named "d3p" and from that I decided to mimic a part of `magrittr` package with a `+` instead of a `%>%`

```
pipe <- function()
{
  function(lhs, rhs)
  {
    # the parent environment
    parent <- parent.frame()

    # the environment in which to evaluate pipeline
    env    <- new.env(parent = parent)

    # split the pipeline/chain into its parts.
    chain_parts <- split_chain(match.call(), env = env)

    pipes <- chain_parts[["pipes"]] # the pipe operators.
    rhss  <- chain_parts[["rhss" ]] # the right-hand sides.
    lhs   <- chain_parts[["lhs"  ]] # the left-hand side.

    # Create the list of functions defined by the right-hand sides.
    env[["_function_list"]] <-
      lapply(1:length(rhss),
             function(i) wrap_function(rhss[[i]], pipes[[i]], parent))

    # Create a function which applies each of the above functions in turn.
    env[["_fseq"]] <-
      `class<-`(eval(quote(function(value) freduce(value, `_function_list`)),
                     env, env), c("fseq", "function"))

    # make freduce available to the resulting function
    # even if magrittr is not loaded.
    env[["freduce"]] <- freduce

    # Result depends on the left-hand side.
    if (is_placeholder(lhs)) {
      # return the function itself.
      env[["_fseq"]]
    } else {
      # evaluate the LHS
      env[["_lhs"]] <- eval(lhs, parent, parent)

      # compute the result by applying the function to the LHS
      result <- withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env))

      # If compound assignment pipe operator is used, assign result
      if (is_compound_pipe(pipes[[1L]])) {
        eval(call("<-", lhs, result[["value"]]), parent, parent)
        # Otherwise, return it.
      } else {
        if (result[["visible"]])
          result[["value"]]
        else
          invisible(result[["value"]])
      }
    }
  }
}

#' @export
`+.d3p`  <- pipe()
```

That didn't work and I would like to know how to use a plus for some classes. The goal of this is to follow `ggplot2` as a standard.

Comment: Type this at your R console: ` methods("+") . There's no such operation as "append an S3 class to my functions". You can add function to a generic such as "+" that will handle objects of particular class and then you can make an object of that class that will get dispatched to that function.
`

Comment: _"The goal of this is to follow ggplot2 as a standard."_ It is probably good to know, that if `ggplot` would be developed now it would use the `%>%` pipe (just like `ggvis` does), not the `+`.